# Adicionar, atualizar ou apagar dado de uma coluna ao adicionar, atualizar ou apagar mesmo dado de outra coluna:

Tags: sql, oracle, trigger

Olá! Estou iniciando em programação Java e também em Oracle SQL e estou com um problema:

Preciso que determinado registro de uma coluna de uma tabela seja atualizado, adicionado ou removido de uma coluna de uma outra tabela. Por exemplo:

```
tabela1 -- nome
tabela2 -- identificador
```

quando adicionar um nome:

```
insert into tabela1 values ('usuario');
```

o nome 'usuario' também seja registrado na tabela2, em identificador;

quando remover um nome:

```
delete from tabela1 where nome = 'usuario';
```

apague também o mesmo registro na tabela2;

quando atualizar um nome:

```
update tabela1 set nome = 'usuario_2021' where nome = 'usuario';
```

aconteça o mesmo com o identificador da tabela2.

até agora, só consegui criar um trigger que adiciona o mesmo registro nas duas tabelas, mas quando deleto este registro da tabela1, o registro permanece na tabela2.

```
create table nome1 (
nome_1 varchar2(50));

create table nome2 (
nome_2 varchar2(50));

create or replace trigger trgg
after insert or update or delete on nome1
for each row
begin
INSERT INTO nome2(nome_2) VALUES(:new.nome_1);
end;
```

obrigado pela ajuda! abraços!

EDIT:

Consegui fazer um arremedo que funciona, mas não parece bom, ficou bem feio o código, eu acho...

```
create or replace trigger trgg
after insert or update or delete on nome1
for each row
begin
if inserting then
insert into nome2(nome_2) values(:new.nome_1);
end if;
if updating then
delete from nome2 where nome_2 = nome_2;
insert into nome2(nome_2) values(:new.nome_1);
end if;
if deleting then
delete from nome2 where nome_2 = nome_2;
end if;
end;
```

Comment: Existe o tratamento IF INSERTING THEN ...  UPDATING  DELETING https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18147/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG52100

Comment: A solução seria esta mesmo , só o delete,insert poderia ser um update.